# how to call API with form-data in AJAX jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, multipartform-data

[image]

I want to hit a API with multi-part form-data with a header as (X-VN-APPTOKEN:967fdasog44d4dfvcb573dsfqw43098d) and two param one is file. Its working fine in postman , but by AJAX its not sending RESPONSE. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader("X-VN-APPTOKEN-APPTOKEN", "967fdasog44d4dfvcb573dsfqw43098d");
  },
  url: "/path/to/handler",
  data: '...', // your data
  processData: false,
  success: function(msg) {
    // handle results
  }
});
```

You can add `type` parameter (such as json) for auto parse result and so on.

Comment: i added data as   var data = new FormData();
                    data.append('fname', 'abc'); , but its not success response come